# Making a REST request to collect the page view from Google analytics

Tags: python, rest, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am newbie in GA I just want to make a rest REquest to my program  to the google analytics to get the page view b/w specifics date for my website .

I gone through the google devlopers api but could not understand too much .

Please give me some example to do this are some good docs is alos fine with examples .

Some more clarification .

I want to make REST request on google analytics to get the per page view details like how mane users have visited the page in a timeframe .

I want these data to be Json or xml formats like Youtube anf google calendar api .

Comment: I think what you need for your python script is here: _[gdata-python-client](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-python-client/)_,otherwise please explain your question better.

Comment: Did you read this **[Management API - Using Python](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtPython)** and **[Management API - Using REST](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtRest)**?

Comment: Thanks your suggestion helps me only one more thiing I wanted to know that how can I get the access token to access the analytics  for REST request

Comment: you're welcome ;), I posted my answer.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is here ***[Management API - Using Python](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtPython)*** and ***[Management API - Using REST‌​](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtRest)*** *(as I mentioned in comments)*.
For get the access token and work with it you need OAuth 2.0 authorization protocol from Google API client library for python, so all you need is **[OAuth 2.0 Google API Client for Python](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/aaa_oauth)**